# soup.find_all and find_elements_by_class return no elements found

Tags: python, selenium, findall

I have tried two methods to find betting odd values with no results. I get nothing.

Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pandas as pd

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.optibet.lv/sport/wcg/CS:GO-5541")

odds = driver.find_elements_by_class('event-block-row__odd event-block-row__odd_clickable event-block-row__odd_without-middle-odd')

if odds is not None:
    print('found odds element')
    print(odds)
```

This didn't work. It just prints 'found odds element'. I then tried to change the class name to `odds = driver.find_elements_by_class('odd__value')` to no avail.
After that I tried to use BeautifulSoup:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.optibet.lv/sport/wcg/CS:GO-5541"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

containers = soup.find_all("div", class_="event-block-row__odd event-block-row__odd_clickable event-block-row__odd_without-middle-odd")
print (len(containers))
```

This returns '0'. I'm out of ideas and not very experienced. Any help?

Comment: Everything is in an iframe.

Comment: @arundeep chohan I see now, thank you.

Comment: I put the answer if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to the iframe prior to getting the class. Then loop the list.

```
driver.get("https://www.optibet.lv/sport/wcg/CS:GO-5541")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#iFrameResizer0"))
odds = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('odd__value')

if odds is not None:
    print('found odds element')
    for odd in odds:
        print(odd.text)
```

Comment: This does the trick. Thank you. How did you realise it was inside an iframe just by looking at it?

Comment: The first thing you do when checking xpath, class names is to see if it's an iframe. If it's an iframe you generally will end up with trying too many find elements and none of them will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Many sites have a scraper protection and in a second place your site is very heavy. You can try this but BeautifulSoup has limitations:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

url_1 = 'https://www.optibet.lv/sport/wcg/CS:GO-5541'
sauce_1  = urllib.request.urlopen(url_1).read()
soup_1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce_1, 'lxml')

for table in soup_1.find('div', class_='event-block-row__odd event-block-row__odd_clickable event-block-row__odd_without-middle-odd'):
    print(table.text)
```

Comment: I hope this help but I can't open the site because is too heavy...

Comment: Yes, thank you. That's why I switched to selenium. Even with user agent I got the 403 error using bs. I believe it can be done with both selenium and BeautifulSoup, but sticking to the prior one will be easier. Thank you again! :)

Comment: Ok can you leave a like please? :-)

Comment: I did, but it won't show up because my rep is too low, sorry.